# Rails is changing returned JSON into HTML

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

When a JSON is returned from an API call in my Rails app I get this response:

```
&quot;{\&quot;stdout\&quot;:\&quot;2\\n\&quot;,\&quot;stderr\&quot;:\&quot;\&quot;,\&quot;wallTime\&quot;:241,\&quot;exitCode\&quot;:0}&quot;
```

When it should look like this:

```
{"stdout": "2\n", "stderr": "", "wallTime": 241, "exitCode": 0}
```

How do I change this bearing in mind the response is being dealt with in JavaScript?

The JS handling the response:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $(".edit_code_lesson").on("ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
    result = JSON.parse(data)
    alert(result);
  ).bind "ajax:error", (e, xhr, status, error) ->
    console.log(status + '\n ' + error);
    console.log(xhr);
```

It is after inspecting the `xhr` I noticed the HTML formatted JSON was being returned. A Syntax error is being thrown.

This is the controller fetching the API:

```
def evaluate
  @code_lesson = CodeLesson.find(params[:code_lesson][:id])
  @language = Language.find(@code_lesson.language_id).slug
  @sandie = Sandie.new(language: @language)
  @code = @sandie.evaluate(code: params[:code_lesson][:user_code]).to_json
end
```

Comment: are you using the JSON module or hand-building?

Comment: @dandavis don't quite understand the question? I'm using the API wrapper [Sandie](https://github.com/rafalchmiel/sandie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, do this:

```
render :json => your_params, :status => 200
```

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly does it appear like that? Already in the controller? Or somewhere on your site after you render it? You can render with

```
<% raw @some_stuff %>
```

or

```
<%== @some_stuff %>
```

to avoid such conversions. (If @some_stuff is already a string). What do you want to do there? just render it as HTML or generate a JSON object?